# how to put two conditions in sum in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, dataset

```
frames 
Datetime                   ratio               dif
2022-06-09 12:33:00 -0.3861241598107547     -299.50183804712964
2022-06-09 12:34:00 -0.360130489922861      -274.88184087028105
2022-06-09 12:35:00 -0.22108950904852795    -166.02672464097395
2022-06-09 12:36:00 -0.18316426991752388    -135.2928226604197
2022-06-09 12:37:00 -0.09932437001820388    -72.14644129886278
2022-06-09 12:38:00 -0.0820362738010348     -58.58522049972339
```

I want to count how many times dif > 15 and ratio > 0.05
so i tested the following

```
total_enhancements = (frames['dif'] > 15 & frames['ratio'] > 0.05 ).sum()
```

The output is

> TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [float64] array and
> scalar of type [bool]

what can i do instead ?

Answer (score 0):

You need use brackets or to use [`Series.gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html)

```
total_enhancements = ((frames['dif'] > 15) & (frames['ratio'] > 0.05)).sum()
```

Or:

```
total_enhancements = (frames['dif'].gt(15) & frames['ratio'].gt(0.05)).sum()
```

Or:

```
total_enhancements = frames['dif'].gt(15).mul(frames['ratio'].gt(0.05)).sum()
```